# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64?

Tags: c, macos, debugging

I am trying to compile and run a project on VS Code on Mac but I am getting the mentions error anybody has any idea on what am I missing?

```
[Running] cd "/Users/aditisingh/Desktop/asm4/" && gcc main.c -o main && "/Users/aditisingh/Desktop/asm4/"main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_AddArc", referenced from:
      _main in main-4ad7ac.o
  "_AddNode", referenced from:
      _main in main-4ad7ac.o
  "_EmptyGraph", referenced from:
      _main in main-4ad7ac.o
  "_PrintAllArcs", referenced from:
      _main in main-4ad7ac.o
  "_mspK", referenced from:
      _main in main-4ad7ac.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.262 seconds
```

Comment: Is all your code in `main.c`? It looks like you're calling functions from other files, but aren't compiling them.

Comment: This is a problem with VS Code in general, for multi-file projects you need to use an external build-system which supports multiple files. VS Code doesn't support it by itself.

Comment: Why are you compiling with gcc and linking with clang?

Comment: @stark On macOS the installation of Clang will create an alias for `gcc` to invoke `clang`.